# mysql relational question. Get results when M:N null

Tags: mysql, sql, join, null, relational-database

### -Goal-

I would like to fetch users who do not have an entry within the 'bar' table. These users will also belong to a certain 'usergroup' and have restrictions within the 'user' table itself.

### Simplified table structure

#### User

```
userid - auto-increment    
username - string    
userage - integer    
usergroup_usergroupid - foreign key
```

#### usergroup

```
usergroup - auto-increment    
usergroupname - string
```

#### user_has_bar

```
user_userid - foreign key    
bar_barid - foreign key
```

### -Query...so far-

```
SELECT username     
FROM user as u, usergroup as ug, user_has_bar as ub    
WHERE    
u.usergroup_usergroupid = ug.usergroupid AND    
u.userage = 10 AND  <-- lets pretend this exists    
u.location_locationid = 1 AND <-- Same here     
u.userid ... ub.user_userid;
```

### -Headache-

It is this last line that has me throwing up blanks. I believe from what I have read up on, the way to perform this operation is with a LEFT JOIN. However, everything i have read so far ends up being quite confusing.

If possible, I would like to keep this operation within a mySQL query and then optimise later.It is created by a PHP mySQL generator I coded and I would like to understand the simple syntax and then dig more in to it. Any approach is VERY welcome though

Thank you kindly for reading this question.

Comment: Relational answer: [anti-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin) `user` and `user_has_bar`, but methinks you aren't asking a relational question after all ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT username
    FROM user u
        INNER JOIN usergroup ug
            ON u.usergroup_usergroupid = ug.usergroupid 
        LEFT JOIN user_has_bar ub
            ON u.userid = ub.user_userid
    WHERE u.userage = 10
        AND u.location_locationid = 1
        AND ub.user_userid IS NULL
```

Comment: Wow, you got back to me with a response fast! Thank you very much. I'll just try it out and post result. What I would say from having a quick peruse, it looks an elegant and simple solution, often the best

Comment: @Simon Ball: As a side note, I'm not sure the INNER JOIN to usergroup is even needed as you don't seem to be referencing any columns from that table, unless you're just trying to guarantee the user is assigned to a group.

Comment: Five star answer, it worked perfectly. Thank you very much Joe. Have a brew on me!

Comment: Stafanelli: Your assumption about ensuring users are from a certain group is correct Joe. I've just simplified the query in terms of making the question seem complete